# エクセルのセルのようなマスに数値を入れて、真偽をチェックするアプリの効率的なテスト方法はありませんか？

Tags: javascript, html

クロスワードのようにエクセルのセルのようなマスに数値を入れて、真偽をチェックするアプリの効率的なテスト方法はありませんか？

セルのinput要素に、自分でたくさんの数値を毎回入れて、うまく動かなかったら、修正して、また、入れ直すという作業が大変です。

もちろん始めは、すべてinput要素のvalueに数値をいれて、うまくいったら、空のセルを作って、もう一度、自分でアプリのユーザーと同じように、数値を入れてちゃんと正しい真偽チェックするという方法は自分でも考えられるのですが、もっと効率的に行う方法はないでしょうか？

すべてinput要素のvalueに数値をいれて、からまた、削除するというのが大変すぎます。

jsで作っています。

最後に、実際にtableタグのなかにあるinput要素に、大変な思いをして、数値をすべて入れたのですが、エラーが出てしまいました。リロードすると、数値が消えてしまうのですが、これを保存しておいたり、簡単にコピペできるようにする、ないしはコピペする方法はないでしょうか？

ブラウザ上で、コピペしたのですが、一列の文字列になってしまいました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

テストとして正しい手順を踏むなら`Selenium WebDriver`というブラウザの操作を自動化できるものがありますので、jsを使うのでしたら`nodejs`でテストを書くことで実現できると思います。

ただ、そこまで難しいことをしなくても

```
default_values = [[1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6],
                  [7,8,9]];
```

のように2次元配列を作って、それぞれのinput要素を`default_values[0][0]`などを使い初期化すれば、一箇所を編集するだけでよいのでかなり楽になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 回答をhtmlタグのvalue属性に直接入れずにjsであえて全て入れると少し楽になるという事ですね。

Answer (score 0):

以下のようにして、ページ読込時にinput要素に数値を設定するのはいかがでしょうか。

- HTML

  ```
  <table id="fields">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ```
- JavaScript

  ```
  //ページ読込完了時にshowValues()を実行する
  window.onload = function(){
     showValues();
  };


  //DOM操作により、各セルのinput要素に値を設定する
  function showValues(){

    var fields = document.getElementById("fields");
    var trs = fields.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
      var tr = trs[i]
      var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");

      for(var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++){
        var td = tds[j];
        var input = td.getElementsByTagName("input");
        input[0].value = getRandomValue();
      }

    }

  }


  //ランダムな数値を取得する
  function getRandomValue(){
      //1~100のランダムな整数を生成
      return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
  }
  ```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ランダムは数値を入れてテストするという事ですか？

Comment: input要素にどのような数値が入力されるのか、質問文中に記述がなかったため、仮の値としてランダムな値を入力するようにしました。値を取得する関数は、必要に応じて、適切な値を返すようにしてください。